# How to write a loop that generates range intervals in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm newbie here. I want to ask about for loops in PHP.
How to write code that will output this:

```
i =1;
j = 0-20;
```

then if `i=2; j = 20-40`,

```
i=3; j=40-60,
```

and so on.

Notes: j is range data from 0-(+20);

I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 1; range = 0-20;
i = 2; range = 20-40;
i = 3; range = 40-60;
...
```

You wrote the pattern yourself: *"range data from 0-(+20)"*. You have 3 variables there, `i` and range defined by `min` and `max`. You need to take some time thinking how each of these will change based on how `i` will change. Then it shouldn't be hard to come up with something like this:

```
$rangeSize = 20;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $rangeMin = $i * $rangeSize;
    $rangeMax = $rangeMin + $rangeSize;
    echo "$i : $rangeMin - $rangeMax" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

output:

```
0 : 0 - 20
1 : 20 - 40
2 : 40 - 60
3 : 60 - 80
4 : 80 - 100
5 : 100 - 120
6 : 120 - 140
7 : 140 - 160
8 : 160 - 180
9 : 180 - 200
```

Comment: thanks for answer. my question is the 0-20, 20-40, etc is for loop too. not just a range. I think i have my answer by myself. but i'm glad for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something along those lines
refer to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp for the official documentation

```
 <?php 
        $max_i = put the maximum value for i here
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $max_i; $i++) 
        {
            echo "i = $i <br>";
            echo "j = $i*20 - 20 <br>";
        } 
    ?>
```